# Problems with Inserting 1 in Missing Numbers

Tags: python

I want to find the missing numbers in a given list. The problem here is when 1 is not in the list, it won't return 1 as one of the missing numbers. Another one is when the list is un-ordered, and 1 is the last number in the list, it will return 1 as one of the missing numbers.

```
>>> def missing_numbers(num_list):
    original_list = [x for x in range(num_list[0], num_list[-1] + 1)]
    num_list = set(num_list)
    print (list(num_list ^ set(original_list)))


>>> missing_numbers([1,2,3,4,5,10,11])
[6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> missing_numbers([2,3,4,5,10,11])
[6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> missing_numbers([2,3,4,5,10,11,1])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11]
>>> missing_numbers([2,3,4,5,10,11])
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You have the same problem on the other side, it doesn't report 12, 13 and 14 as missing either.

Comment: What would the missing numbers in `[]` be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the list can be unordered then don't use `num_list[0]` and `num_list[-1]` as the range limits. Use `min` and `max` instead:

```
original_list = list(range(min(num_list), max(num_list)+1))
```

Also, a `set` can be directly constructed from the return value (list / iterator depending on Python version) of `range`.

Edit: if you always want 1 as the minimum value:

```
original_list = list(range(1, max(num_list)+1))
```

Comment: But this will be missing 1 which OP wants if the input list is `[2,3,4,5,10,11]`

Comment: No, if 1 is missing, then min(num_list) is 2. In fact if min and max can be missing then he can't figure out what min and max are from num_list at all.

Comment: sadly, the 1 is still missing.

Comment: I can't just start with 1 because the numbers will be picked from the DB. And these are based on the numbers selected by the users. 1 might not be in the list from start and I don't want to make it a must to start from 1. I hope you get my point? @meowgoesthedog

Comment: If list starts with, say 3. With what number does the missing_list should begin? How is this determined.

Comment: @bobozar I don't understand and you should clarify in your question. You first said the 1 is missing, and now you say that if the list doesn't contain 1 `original_list` shouldn't always start from 1. That sounds contradictory to me. What is it that you **actually** want? The examples you provided are incomplete, and you are not telling us the whole story.

Comment: For example, there are four positions, position 1, 2, 3 and 4. 2 different users select position 2 and 4 each. now this will be  `position_selected = [2, 4]` now I need to find the missing or available positions. another example, `position_selected = [1,3]` now I need to find the missing or available positions. In this case, I guess I should provide the total number of positions to solve this issue. Yet to wrap my head around a better solution. @meowgoesthedog

Comment: @bobozar this example doesn't help, because the set of valid numbers still starts from 1, whereas you said earlier that you don't want it to.

Comment: This still is too vague with respect to the examples given in your question. See my answer maybe that helps? Why are the "available positions" not known to begin with??

Answer (score 1):

This is just not going to work, the problem is ill defined. You simply cannot know which numbers are missing *just* from  a list of numbers that aren't missing.

If the input is `[1,2,3]`, how can you say `4` should be there or not? What if the input is `[]`, then you know nothing.

A comment by OP confirms this:

> I can't just start with 1 because the numbers will be picked from the DB. And these are based on the numbers selected by the users. 1 might not be in the list from start and I don't want to make it a must to start from 1.

You *don't even know* whether missing 1 in your examples is actually wrong.

This function cannot be made, it has to be clairvoyant.

You need to make a new function that takes `(number_list, minvalue, maxvalue)` as its arguments and figure out how to supply them.

Comment: Yeah doesn't make any sense, as if list starts with 3 ex: [3,6,7]. How can we determine the first number that is missing? It can't be fixed to 1 as OP said.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

```
def missing_numbers(num_list):
    start = 1
    end = num_list[len(num_list)-1]
    missing_list = [item for item in range(start, end) if item not in num_list]
    return missing_list
```

O/P

```
missing_numbers([1,2,5])
[3, 4]
```

Comment: Isn't that essentially the same thing he has now, with the same problems?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Oh, Then checking from range 1 should solve the problem. Fixed it. Thanks !

Comment: I think checking from 1 always is a first improvement but it's just a nonsense problem, you can't know which numbers are missing just from the ones that are present.

Comment: Yeah, Starting from 1 is still vague.

Answer (score 0):

With your constraints, I suggest making a start and end value and making sure they follow those rules but seems 1 - the largest value in `num_list` would work

```
def missing_numbers(num_list):
    return list(set(num_list) ^ set(range(1, max(num_list) + 1)))
```

This can also be done with `itertools.filterfalse`

```
from itertools import filterfalse

def missing_numbers(num_list):
    return list(filterfalse(num_list.__contains__, range(1, max(num_list) + 1)))
```

**Edit**

Since nobody can come up with a good reasoning as to what OP wants as the `start` and `end`. I say, make the method accept a start and end value.

```
from itertools import filterfalse

def missing_numbers(numbers, start = 1, end = None):
    if not end:
        end = max(numbers) + 1
    if start >= end:
        raise TypeError("End must be greater than start")

    #I just prefer the readability of the filterfalse method over
    #the set one, but use whatever fits your fancy
    return list(filterfalse(numbers.__contains__, range(start, end)))
```